# Are CUSIP case sensitive

Tags: programming

Are CUSIP identifiers case sensitive like RIC number are?

Answer (score 4):

CUSIPs are not case sensitive.

Any letters within a CUSIP are upper case.

The CUSIP identifier was developed in 1967 by ABA and has not changed significantly.

The specification for CUSIP is detailed here:
https://www.cusip.com/pdf/CUSIP_Intro_03.14.11.pdf
This provides some further detail about how letters (instead of digits) are used, and mainly relate to debt securities and international issues.